# MySql Trigger without writing access

Tags: mysql

So I want to write a trigger that updates (insert, update, delete) a table if another table(in another database) gets updated, something like this for example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_data
AFTER INSERT ON account
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO test4.bank3
SET
money = NEW.amount
```

The problem is that I only have reading access to the other database (in this example where account lies on).

Is there a way around it or do I have to use a completely different method?

Comment: if there was a way around it, what would be the point of the security restriction (i.e. read-only access)? The only way round it is to run the command as a user with the correct permissions.

Comment: But I have reading access.
What I can do (and already did) is that I can write a function that I have to use manually that inserts all the information I need in my table.
So why isn't it possible to write a trigger or doing it on another automatic way?

Comment: if you only have reading access, how does your other function manage to work, if it does the same task?

Comment: I've got enough access to read and copy files or do something like an INSERT INTO from this database.
But the Trigger would be in this database, not mine and that's something I don't have access to (like changing or inserting new files in this other database)

Comment: ah you're saying you don't have permission to create the trigger. That wasn't clear at all. It sounded like you didn't have permission to run an INSERT. In that case no of course there's no way round it, for the same security reasons. You'll have to ask the DBA to create the trigger for you, or ask them to grant you the relevant permission.

Comment: Doesn't really makes sense to me, bc I can just do the same thing 'manually'. Ok, trigger could do more than that, but.... 
Anyway... Thank you for your help ~

And sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: It makes perfect sense as far as I can see. The permissions for doing an insert (i.e. creating a row in a table) are not the same as the permissions for doing DDL operations such as creating triggers, tables etc. You can have permissions for one thing but not the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you ask the admin of the other database to set up a connection / trigger so that a duplicate table is made in your database? Then you could use that table as the trigger?

Comment: Well, probably gonna ask for something like that. Just hoped there would be another way.

Comment: Cool, as others have said I don't think there is unfortunately, otherwise we could all really start messing round with each others databases!!